# jQuery POST always failing

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express, http-headers

I've created a Node.js server using Express with a pretty simple configuration:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.json({foo: 'bar'});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Upon inspection, here is the data Firefox logged about the network request to the `/login` route:

```
Request URL:    http://localhost:3000/login
Request Method:     POST
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

And here are the request headers:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: null
Host:   localhost:3000
Content-Type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

As far as I can tell, everything appears to be fine up until this point. However, in my jQuery code, the fail() callback is always being called:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
    data: {foo: 'bar'},
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function() {
    console.log('done');
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log('fail');
});
```

This is what my response header looks like:

```
X-Powered-By:   Express
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Date:   Fri, 17 Jan 2014 07:12:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

How to I configure my Express or jQuery setup to properly handle JSON responses?

Comment: Try modifying your jQuery AJAX call like [**this**](http://pastebin.com/vNVwAnMB) and check what error you get.

Comment: @srvikram13 Made the changes, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',  ///<------do this
   data: {foo: 'bar'},
   dataType: 'jsonp',  //<---for cross domain json data access
   contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8"  //<----add this
})
.done(function() {
   console.log('done');
})
.fail(function() {
   console.log('fail');
});
```

Check if your server is setup with correct headers *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain-you-are-connecting-from.com/");
```

#### Update:

For cross domain json data access can be done with `jsonp` dataType.

#### From the docs:

**JSONP**

If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: The request is cross-domain, so I've been using the full address. I did add in the contentType, but it still didn't work.

Comment: then you have to use `jsonp` instead of `json`

Comment: OK that makes sense, but unfortunately it's still failing

Comment: Hmm... then if you could verify that your server has been setup to send data for cross domain access.If you hit the url what does it show in the browser?

Comment: thanks for the help, I wouldn't have thought of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` bit. Here is what helped me get it working: http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html